# /var/log/messages keeps on repopulating

Tags: logging, fedora, rsyslog

I need to clear all the rsyslog logs so, I stop the rsyslog and remove file.log as well as /var/log/messages. But as soon as I restart the service, all the logs start popping up again (400k lines). I looked up some more information and it seems that the StateFile is not being saved somewhere. I tried to create /var/spool/rsyslog dir with 777 permissions but that did not solve the issue as well and the file.log keeps on getting repopulated over and over again and it doesnot stop until the log files have all the nonsense logs back in it.

I have a logfile configured as following in ../rsyslog.d
local0.* /home/user/file.log

My OS is Pidora and I am running
pidora rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.2" x-pid="1150" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"]

**How do I clear all the rsyslog cleanly and stop rsyslog from repopulating it???? Been stuck with this for couple of days now.**

Misc. Information: I am also noticing whole bunch of the following errors in /var/log/messages
Nov 28 12:26:51 pidora rsyslogd-2177: imjournal: begin to drop messages due to rate-limiting
Nov 28 12:36:07 pidora rsyslogd-2177: imjournal: 334681 messages lost due to rate-limiting

Answer (score 0):

The reason the logs reappear once you restart rsyslog is because there is a process that is continually logging those messages, so many that rsyslog is rate limiting them. Based on the time between those two log prints you provided, it appears to be printing **~570 logs per second**. I need more log output to help you figure out what is going on.

**You have two options**

1. **(recommended)** Figure out why the process in question is spewing those messages and fix it so that the messages will stop. Could it be related to [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1123190%20this%20bug?)?
2. **(not recommended)** Add a filter to your rsyslog config just after the modules section. This is NOT a solution you want to use long term because it removes ALL messages from the process in question, not just those that you want to remove. This could mean that you could miss seeing important error messages. Something like this would do it:

   `if $programname == '<processname>' then ~`

It's important to **resolve the problem** and not just filter it, because on a Raspberry Pi you will be running on flash based memory. It's possible that you will wear out the SD card faster if a process is continually logging a ton of messages and you run it for an extended period of time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bob.  The process spewing these messages is written by myself actually and selecting rsyslog was due the fact that it could handle fast logging. Unfortunately, option2 does not work either because I already have a filter that is saving the log to a local file. I am trying to run logrotate on that file to make sure that the size does not get out of control for that. The problem is that when the logrotate executes, my log file starts pulling everything from the beginning of time. That totally defeats the purpose of logrotating.

Comment: What I want is that I should be able to logrorate without rsyslog pulling everything since the beginning of time every single time logrotates.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "pulling everything since the beginning of time". You don't want it to repopulate the log once it rotates? Normally, after logrotate is executed, a 'HUP' is sent to rsyslog telling it to update it's file references.

Comment: So, for example lets take a sample file.log that accumulates "A B C D .... Z\0" string in one day. Assume at the start of the day 6am, file.log has entries "A B C". At this point, if I do a logrotate on this  file.log, a backup file <file.log-20150122> will be created with contents "A B C \0". 

From this point on, file.log should continue from "D E F.... " but what I actually see is " A B C D E F"... and that is what I mean by it pulling everything in file.log from the beginning of time when it should not. The only way I have been able to get around this problem is by rm /var/log/journal/*

Comment: I am thinking that  rsyslog should be creating a statefile for file.log but that statefile somehow is not doing its job.... I dont know if I am on the right track...... Thanks for looking into this Bob

Comment: Please add the relevant logrotate config as well as your rsyslog.conf file to the question. It's possible the logrotate config is wrong.